# API documentation via a gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, documentation

I'm trying to find out if there's a gem that can document an API by automatically detecting changes to the inputs/outputs of the endpoints and produce documentation (HTML or whatever) detailing the API, perhaps in the style of

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/statuses/home_timeline.

Comment: Almost 100% sure there is no such thing. Especially not in Rails as there is simply too little metadata to detect that kind of changes automatically

Comment: same question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10289024/generate-and-publish-ruby-based-rest-apis-documentation/10294257#comment13253524_10294257

Comment: Check ApiDoco gem https://rubygems.org/gems/apidoco/versions/1.2.0 for rails 5 api documentation. It is very easy to setup and has a good user experience.

Answer (score 2):

As far as gems are concerned, [apipie-rails](https://github.com/Pajk/apipie-rails) is nice. It won't automatically detect changes per se, but it does have a simple, annotative syntax. You can generate documentation automatically based on your tests, and it has provides some DRY help for things like param groups that are used repeatedly.

And now for something completely different... [apiary](http://apiary.io/) gives you a lot of goodies based on a markdown blueprint of your API (maintained at the root of your repo). Maintaining the blueprint isn't a terrible price to pay considering apiary then provides documentation, code samples, community commenting, and even a proxy API server if you want.

Comment: Lately I have used http://readme.io/ + http://apidocjs.com/ in a few projects. Not a gem. Not free. But an excellent value.

Answer (score 0):

This is the closest thing I'm aware of, but it's less of an add-on gem and more of a tool for building your API with documentation baked in: https://github.com/mattetti/Weasel-Diesel