# Generate and publish Ruby based REST APIs documentation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, rest, code-generation

What are cool kids using nowadays to easily parse/generate/publish REST APIs? I took a look on [Swagger](http://swagger.wordnik.com/) and It looks nice but from my point of view it doesn't fit ok with Ruby. Maybe I'm just wrong and I'm missing something, help would be appreciated.

Comment: Seems great, but it also seems do require a lot of work to setup

Comment: Exactly, it looks awesome but it has a ton of dependencies I would like to avoid.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Sounds like you don't have an API yet?  If that's the case, this is the approach that I recommend.

- Create an *interface* for the API by using the [swagger-specification](https://github.com/wordnik/swagger-core/wiki).  You can do this without using a server, [see here](https://github.com/wordnik/swagger-core/tree/master/samples/no-server).
- Verify the interface by using [swagger-ui](https://github.com/wordnik/swagger-ui/downloads).  This allows you to see all the endpoints that you've defined (still, no coding, except for the json files!)
- Once you have an interface you want, use [swagger-codegen](https://github.com/wordnik/swagger-codegen) to build a stubbed-out version of your server.  There are currently templates for [nodejs](https://github.com/wordnik/swagger-codegen/tree/master/samples/server-generator/node) and [scalatra](https://github.com/wordnik/swagger-codegen/tree/master/samples/server-generator/scalatra) with more on the way.  Making a new server generator is simply a matter of creating/modifying some mustache templates.
- You can also generate your client with swagger-codegen.

The beauty of this is that you can do interface-driven development of your API.  Build the interfaces and fill in the blanks.  The plumbing is done for you.

Comment: Prototype ruby support is now available (note!  changes will be coming to make more ruby-ish):  https://github.com/wordnik/swagger-codegen/tree/master/samples/server-generator/sinatra

Answer (score 8):

We've just started playing with [apipie](https://github.com/Pajk/apipie-rails) for this. So far seems pretty neat.

Comment: Thanks, looks promising I'll keep this in mind for a future project. Already using swagger for the app I was talking about when I posted the question.

Answer (score 6):

Swagger can be used with ruby as client  to automatically generate client libraries from a Swagger-compliant server https://github.com/wordnik/swagger-codegen

If you use RoR than I think you should look at https://github.com/elc/rapi_doc , but it is not easy to use.

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer, well, I think I'll give `rapi_doc` a try. It doesn't look as sexy as Swagger but at least its setup is way simpler.

Comment: That rapi_doc link is broken. I found it forked in various places e.g. https://github.com/phuc/rapi_doc Looks like it hasn't really been maintained since 2008 though

Answer (score 5):

Please have a look at ApiDoco gem (https://github.com/72pulses/apidoco/) for documentation. It is very easy to setup and has a good user experience.