# How do you generate REST API documentation from routes.rb with parameter information

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rest

I would like to specify expected parameters for various REST calls in my routes.rb file so that they are documented via

rake routes
   http://localhost:3000/rails/info/routes

As a simple example, take the following routes

```
GET  /api/v3/posts/:post_id/comments(.:format) api/v3/comments#index
POST /api/v3/posts/:post_id/comments(.:format) api/v3/comments#create
```

GET comments can take an optional parameter *paging_key* while create has all the fields that it needs to create a comment.

I would like to be able to generate a doc so that front end developers know how to use the API.

Comment: This question may provide clues: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10289024/generate-and-publish-ruby-based-rest-apis-documentation

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, no facility for this exists by annotating routes.rb. Typically, you would document your controller methods with YARDoc (or similar), optionally with a plugin like [yard-restful](https://github.com/kraft001/yard-restful) which adds knowledge of RESTful conventions. It is up to you to specify the URL(s) by which you access that functionality.